# Type consists of class names

Tags: typescript

How to create a type that consists of class names?

Something like that

```
type T1 = Class1.name | Class2.name;
```

Or is it a way to extract `name` property universally from a set of classes?

Comment: The compiler must have complained somethin along the lines of "Class1.name refers to a value but is being used as a type". `Class1.name` is a value - you need its type. You can do that using the `typeof` operator. But if `name` isn't a string literal, you'll only get the type `string`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QIzQN4F8BQGAuBPADgKbQAqyAvNHkQPYBmcCEiAdAHZgC2hA3BtNAD0g6AD1oEbACcAlmwDmAGmgAjQsDABXCMWwALYvEjN2XXQWIATGoRhsa2aBvzZNU4jOwwwwV2BDQHNxAA

Comment: Hello, yes. It is the class name in es6. Yes, `typeof` bypasses all strings.

Comment: In some cases, you _could_ have used [the `as const` trick](https://dev.to/adamcoster/the-typescript-as-const-trick-2f4o), but that won't work on your case as `.name` is a run-time property and type check runs at compile time.